# Usar Doctrine con MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, doctrine, connection

El ejemplo del Boostrap.php de Doctrine contiene por defecto una configuración llamada $conn para hacer uso de una base de datos con sqlite, si se quiere usar MySQL en vez de sqlite, ¿cómo se escribiría ese array de configuración?

Incluyo la variable de configuración:

```
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se usaría lo siguiente:

```
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'DatabaseName',
    'user' => 'DatabaseUser',
    'password' => 'DatabasePassword',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($connectionParams, $config);
```